# Compilation error. unresolved windows_sys::Win32::Foundation

Tags: compilation, windows

I'm on Windows 11, (intel core i7-9700K processor) and have stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default), rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07) and cargo 1.67.1 (8ecd4f20a 2023-01-10)

When I'm compiling some project code, it gives the error `error[E0432]: unresolved import`windows_sys::Win32::Foundation . See the entire error tree below.

Is there any way to overcome this on Windows nativly?  I've just uninstalled and reinstalled via `rust-init.exe`, so it's not that.  Is there an nightly / later release than the one I have above that fixes it?

I expect that I could try going through the kerfuffle of getting everything into and out of WSL2, which may or may not work in the end, but is there some kind of windows_sys::Win32::Foundation shim available to get this working on Windows?
Thanks for any pointers!

***start compilation output with error***

...downloading and compilation successful to here

```rs
Compiling integer-sqrt v0.1.5
Compiling wasmtime-cache v1.0.2
error[E0432]: unresolved import `windows_sys::Win32::Foundation`
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:90:37
|
90 |             use windows_sys::Win32::Foundation::*;
|                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `Foundation` in `Win32`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `windows_sys::Win32::Foundation`
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:3:25
|
3 | use windows_sys::Win32::Foundation::*;
|                         ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `Foundation` in `Win32`

Compiling lru v0.8.1
Compiling trie-root v0.17.0
error[E0412]: cannot find type `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:8:42
|
8 | pub type SignalHandler<'a> = dyn Fn(*mut EXCEPTION_POINTERS) -> bool + Send + Sync + 'a;
|                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0412]: cannot find type `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:22:66
|
22 | unsafe extern "system" fn exception_handler(exception_info: *mut EXCEPTION_POINTERS) -> i32 {
|                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:27:32
|
27 |     if record.ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
|                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:28:36
|
28 |         && record.ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION
|                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:29:36
|
29 |         && record.ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO
|                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:30:36
|
30 |         && record.ExceptionCode != EXCEPTION_INT_OVERFLOW
|                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

Compiling memory-db v0.31.0
Compiling trie-db v0.24.0
Compiling sp-panic-handler v5.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.37#946507ba)
error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `GetCurrentThread` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-cache-1.0.2\src\worker.rs:240:17
 |
240 |                 GetCurrentThread(),
 |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `GetCurrentThreadId`
 |
::: C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-sys-0.36.1\src\Windows\Win32\System\Threading\mod.rs:283:5
 |
283 |     pub fn GetCurrentThreadId() -> u32;
 |     ---------------------------------- similarly named function `GetCurrentThreadId` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `SetThreadPriority` in this scope
 --> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-cache-1.0.2\src\worker.rs:239:13
  |
239  |             SetThreadPriority(
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a constant with a similar name exists: `UmsThreadPriority`
  |
 ::: C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-sys-0.36.1\src\Windows\Win32\System\Threading\mod.rs:1725:1
  |
1725 | pub const UmsThreadPriority: RTL_UMS_THREAD_INFO_CLASS = 2i32;
  | ------------------------------------------------------ similarly named constant `UmsThreadPriority` defined here

Compiling sp-arithmetic v6.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.37#946507ba)
error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualFree` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\instance\allocator\pooling\windows.rs:22:17
|
22 |     if unsafe { VirtualFree(addr as _, len, MEM_DECOMMIT) } == 0 {
|                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `wasmtime-cache` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `CreateFileMappingW` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:114:31
 |
114 |                 let mapping = CreateFileMappingW(
 |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `MapViewOfFile` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:129:27
 |
129 |                 let ptr = MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_EXECUTE, 0, 0, len);
 |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `CloseHandle` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:131:17
 |
131 |                 CloseHandle(mapping);
 |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualProtect` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:146:20
 |
146 |                 if VirtualProtect(ret.ptr as *mut _, ret.len, PAGE_READONLY, &mut old) == 0 {
 |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualProtect` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:396:17
 |
396 |                 VirtualProtect(base, len, PAGE_WRITECOPY, &mut old)
 |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualProtect` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:398:17
 |
398 |                 VirtualProtect(base, len, PAGE_READWRITE, &mut old)
 |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualProtect` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:432:26
 |
432 |             let result = VirtualProtect(base, len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &mut old);
 |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `VirtualFree` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:468:34
 |
468 |                 let r = unsafe { VirtualFree(self.ptr as *mut c_void, 0, MEM_RELEASE) };
 |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `UnmapViewOfFile` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\mmap.rs:471:34
 |
471 |                 let r = unsafe { UnmapViewOfFile(self.ptr as *mut c_void) };
 |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find function, tuple struct or tuple variant `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` in this scope
--> C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\wasmtime-runtime-1.0.2\src\traphandlers\windows.rs:14:8
 |
14  |     if AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, Some(exception_handler)).is_null() {
 |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler`
 |
::: C:\Users\conor\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\windows-sys-0.36.1\src\Windows\Win32\System\Diagnostics\Debug\mod.rs:305:5
 |
305 |     pub fn RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(handle: *const ::core::ffi::c_void) -> u32;
 |     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- similarly named function `RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler` defined here

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0412, E0425, E0432.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `wasmtime-runtime` due to 19 previous errors
```

***end compilation output with error***